# Spaces isometrically isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

$X$ is isometrically isomorphic with $Y$, then we denote by $X \simeq Y$ and, if $X \simeq Z$ for $Z$ a subspace of $Y$, then we denote by $X \preceq Y$ (invented notation).

Prove that $X \simeq Y$, if and only if $X \preceq Y$ and $Y \preceq X$.

It actually looks very natural, but I don't know why I can't write it.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces?

Comment: yes, both are Banach spaces

Comment: Are you comfortable with the fact that compositions of isometric isomorphisms gives an isometric isomorphism?

Comment: I have never proved it, I know that composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism, but not when preserving norm. Although I believe that I can prove it

Comment: I am now doubtful of the result. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein+theorem for Banach spaces. You can inject spaces into one another, but they might not be isomorphic. I've tried playing with it a bit and at some point I needed to invoke this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make things official (and to move the discussion here in case I'm wrong):

I don't think this holds. I believe you need https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein+theorem for this to work, but this is not true for Banach spaces.

Comment: The best reference is: Timothy Gowers, A Solution to the Schroeder-Bernstein Problem for Banach Spaces, Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 28, Issue 3 (1996), 297-304.

Comment: You're right, it's just locked behind a paywall so I decided to give the version that I found. Thank you for the addition though!